Software to find dead code during runtime in Java?
I'm looking for a tool that can find methods that never get invoked during runtime in a Java spring boot application. The only thing I could find is https://github.com/crispab/codekvast which seems to be a dead project.
I'm also considering building my own Java agent that simply keeps track of all method invocations and then checks which methods are not invoked by finding all defined methods.
What's the best way to approach this?

I don't think that this approach is really useful. I use some programs just one or two times a year. And I have quite restrictive Internet connection settings, so you may never notice that I am using those functions.

Basically, the feature you are looking for is called telemetry and there are active projects like https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation

https://github.com/naver/scavenger
is the project built on the idea of codekvast. Please check it out.

Its best to sing its praises a bit more. Tell us whats good about it

More specifically, describe how this product meets the specific needs cited in the Question.
